# Iterating on native base Tabs returns Invariant Violation

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using native base Tabs from the original [docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#tabs-def-headref) (a copy-paste). I am trying to iterate through the Tabs from an axios response. The json looks a little like this (short version):

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 21,
      "user_id": 1,
      "category_id": 5,
      "lang_id": 9,
      "restaurant_id": 1,
      "name": "主菜",
      "image": null,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "2019-08-28 14:41:11",
      "updated_at": "2019-08-28 17:39:47",
    },
    {
      "id": 26,
      "user_id": 1,
      "category_id": 6,
      "lang_id": 9,
      "restaurant_id": 1,
      "name": "甜品",
      "image": null,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "2019-08-28 14:41:32",
      "updated_at": "2019-08-28 17:39:50",
    },
    {
      "id": 31,
      "user_id": 1,
      "category_id": 7,
      "lang_id": 9,
      "restaurant_id": 1,
      "name": "饮料",
      "image": null,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "2019-08-28 14:41:50",
      "updated_at": "2019-08-28 17:39:54",
    }
  ]
}
```

And in my component, I am doing this:

```
render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Header hasTabs />
                <Tabs>

                        {
                            this.state.categories.map((c) => {

                                return (
                                    <Tab heading="test">
                                        <Text>{c.name}</Text>
                                    </Tab>
                                )
                            })
                        }

                </Tabs>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

The category state contains the json as it is. Here is the [error](https://ibb.co/3RVyFVJ) it returns.

I do not understand the error as there are no styling. From what I understand, it is style related right? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try setting the height of the Header. Something like <Header noShadow hasTabs style={{elevation: 0,height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 90 : 50}}>

Comment: Still same error except values are different: https://ibb.co/G90mNLb

Comment: What version are you using? Is it 2.13.0 or less?

Comment: "native-base": "^2.13.4"

Comment: Can you check with 2.13.0? There might be some issue in latest version

Comment: Still same error

Comment: It works if I paste the above json inside the state but it does not work if my axios fetches and sets the state. What maybe the problem?

Comment: As per the discussion, this issue fixedin 2.13.0v.

Comment: Could you please link to the dicussion?

Comment: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2798 and https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2792

Comment: It doesn't work. Downgrading nor upgrading to even 2.13.5 doesn't help still same error

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. The problem was that tabs were being rendered before the data was loaded. So in order to fix that, create a `isLoading` state and put an if statement to check if it has been loaded. The error is because the `<Tabs>` has no child and it was null I suppose.

Hope this fixes someone else with the same issue.